# Transposing data: from repeated measures to independent samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Assume that I conducted an experiment with 20 questions. The questions 1-10 are Type A questions whereas questions 11-20 are Type B questions.

I am wondering whether two types of questions differ from each other.

A natural approach is to calculate the average response for Type A and Type B questions for each participant. Then with a repeated measures t-test, I can test the hypothesis that whether two types of questions are similar or not.

Another approach is to transpose the data (switching rows to columns) and calculating the average response for each question from 1 to 20. Then an independent samples t-test can test whether the rows 1-10 are different from 11-20.

I know that the first approach is commonly used, but I don't know why the second approach is not popular (or is ever used).

Comment: For the second approach, how did you get the conclusion that row 1-10 are independent with row 11-20?

Comment: @user158565 I don't understand your comment. Essentially, they are different questions. There is no duplicate quesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach does not make sense, because the answers are not independent in the sense that the 20 answers from a person are answered by the same person, you cannot really assume that these 20 answers are independent from each other.

Additionally, if you average across people for each question, then you will just have 10 data points for A questions and 10 for B questions. This is to some extent true in a repeated measures model that has a random subject and random question effect (in addition to a fixed "A" vs. "B" effect), too, but I wonder whether further information is lost here.

You could adjust for these issues by bootstrapping - i.e. you randomly draw data for whole subjects with replacement (i.e. in your randomly created dataset that has your original dataset size you can have a single subject multiple times) - and performing that procedure on each of the bootstrap samples. You then get things like tests, estimates, confidence intervals etc. by looking at the distribution of results across these bootstrap samples. However, this is probably more complicated than a repeated measures model (which can also under some assumptions nicely deal with missing data) and probably gives a very similar answer.